Flutter Keyboard Change Numeric To Alphabetic
I have a chat app (Flutter). When user click on "send message" button i want to switch keyboard from numeric state to Alphabetic state if user was on numeric state. Please see the images to understand what i mean. Desired action exists already on What'sApp or Instagram. So in flutter code i want to switch from Numeric State to Alphabetic state.
Numeric Keyboard State

Alphabetic Keyboard State

TextField(
            focusNode: widget.focusNode,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            controller: controller,
            onChanged: onChanged,
            maxLines: 5,
            minLines: 1,
            maxLength: 500,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: "${LocaleKeys.message_single.tr().capitalize()}..",
            ),
            contentInsertionConfiguration: ContentInsertionConfiguration(
              onContentInserted: (c) {
                if (c.hasData) widget.onImageData?.call(c.data!);
              },
            ),
          )

What I Have Tried
I tried changing keyboardType with setState but it didn't work.
I tried closing and re-opening the keyboard but this is not what i wish

You may need to using Native code via platform channel to do that function without reopening the keyboard. Here some document on iOS side https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621110-reloadinputviews?language=objc

@Thanh thanks for your answer! I'm not familiar with Swift but as i understood this is used for custom keyboards. That means i can't use it in default keyboard? And do you know also solution for android part?
